# DynamoDB connection issues from java

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Getting this error when trying create the table in aws service from java :

Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443 [dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/52.94.4.130] failed: connect timed out

The code is --

```
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
            .build(); 

    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

    String tableName = "Music";

    try {
        System.out.println("Attempting to create table; please wait...");
        Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(tableName,
            Arrays.asList(new KeySchemaElement("Artist", KeyType.HASH), // Partition
                                                                      // key
                new KeySchemaElement("SongTitle", KeyType.RANGE)), // Sort key
            Arrays.asList(new AttributeDefinition("Artist", ScalarAttributeType.S),
                new AttributeDefinition("SongTitle", ScalarAttributeType.S)),
            new ProvisionedThroughput(10L, 10L));
        table.waitForActive();
        System.out.println("Success.  Table status: " + table.getDescription().getTableStatus());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to create table: ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Check if the server is up, and if so, check if the ports are open. Try connecting to the database with a client and see if that works.

Comment: Its resolved, the issue was with proxy setting.. Just included the below code in the class and issue got resolved

Comment: ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
  clientConfiguration.setProxyHost(" org proxy site ");
  clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(8000);